# accessing multiple instances in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

so i have a page of products, and for each one i want to cycle through some images on mouseover, and have it stop on mouseout.  the following code is my current state...

initially i had it working where it checked a global variable called repeatCycle to see if it should rotate to the next image.  this caused problems because all the instances of this function were checking & setting the same variable.  i would often get multiple instances running at once.  so i want to set something for each instance instead, but was not able to do it.

i also tried passing it in as an argument to the function, but on the mouseout event when i passed in repeatCycle: false, it would just initialize another instance.

anyone have any suggestions as to how to accomplish this?

```
$.fn.image_cycler = function(options){
  // default configuration properties
  var defaults = {
    fade_delay:     150,
    image_duration: 1500,
  };
  var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

  this.each(function(){
    var product     = $(this);
    var image       = $('div.image>a.product_link>img', product);
    var description = $('div.image>div.description', product);
    var all_images  = $('div.all_images', product);
    var next_image  = ($(all_images).find('img[src="' + $(image).attr('src') + '"]').next('img').attr('src')) ? $(all_images).find('img[src="' + $(image).attr('src') + '"]').next('img') : $(all_images).children('img').first();;

    // mouseover
    image.fadeOut(options.fade_delay, function(){
      image.attr('src', next_image.attr('src'));
      image.fadeIn(options.fade_delay);
    });
    if (this.repeatCycle){
      var loop = function() {
        return this.image_cycler(options);
      }
      setTimeout(loop,options.image_duration);
    }
  });
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div.product').hover(function(){
    $(this).image_cycler();
  }, function(){
    $(this).image_cycler.repeatCycle = false;
  });
});
```

Comment: have you tried the .data function to store data on each element?

Comment: no i am not familiar with it.  im looking through the documentation on it, but it's not clear to me how to store different data for each instance, nor how to access it.  let me experiment with this...  its nice just to have another route to take!

Comment: .data is the first, easiest thing that comes to my mind as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using jQuery's `.data()`. e.g. something like replacing the lines:

```
if (this.repeatCycle){ 
....
$(this).image_cycler.repeatCycle = false;
```

by:

```
if (product.data('repeatCycle')){
....
$(this).data('repeatCycle', false);
```